# How do you decrypt a file that has been encrypted with openssl using nodejs javascript

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptojs

I have a file that has been encrypted using openssl using the following command:

```
openssl enc -in data -out encrypted -e -aes256 -k myverystrongpassword
```

Where data is the original file and encrypted is the encrypted file.

I tried various ways using crypto library but nothing seems to work.  I understand that the password needs to be converted into a key so maybe I am doing something wrong there.  Looked all over for a solution but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do you really mean CryptoJS or the crypto module of NodeJS? Post your code and a sample with ciphertext to be decrypted including passphrase. Which OpenSSL version was used for encryption?

Comment: Either cryptojs or crypto module would work.  I just need a way to do this in an electron app.  These files are encrypted using different versions of OpenSSL they all work the same AFAIK albeit default hashing method has changed over the years so older versions you need to add -md sha256 but current version used on the terminal here is OpenSSL 3.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted OpenSSL statement uses a key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()` to derive a 32 bytes key and a 16 bytes IV from the password in combination with a random 8 bytes salt.
The ciphertext corresponds to the concatenation of the ASCII encoding of `Salted__`, followed by the salt and finally by the actual ciphertext.
As you already know according to your comment, `EVP_BytesToKey()` uses a digest for which OpenSSL applied MD5 by default in earlier versions and SHA-256 as of version v1.1.0 (the default value can be overridden in the OpenSSL statement with the `-md` option).

Decryption is possible e.g. with CryptoJS: Due to its OpenSSL compatibility (s. sec. [Interoperability](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#interoperability)) CryptoJS has a built-in implementation of an accessible `EVP_BytesToKey()` function and additionally allows to explicitly set the digest in the internal `EVP_BytesToKey()` call during key derivation. This makes it possible to decrypt encryptions that used SHA-256 or MD5 in key derivation.

The following data is the Base64 encoding of a ciphertext generated with the posted OpenSSL statement. The plaintext used was *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*. The OpenSSL version applied is v1.1.1i (i.e. SHA-256 is implicitly used in the key derivation):

```
U2FsdGVkX19W4wmC9dD35X4J66cSvaRaIQpvjDKHrLF9+qYg5VTo5urvExHLXhwf/bE8FXJTQZmKN8ITMJVdqQ==
```

This ciphertext can be successfully decrypted using the following CryptoJS implementation:

```js
const password = 'myverystrongpassword';
const saltCiphertextB64 = 'U2FsdGVkX19W4wmC9dD35X4J66cSvaRaIQpvjDKHrLF9+qYg5VTo5urvExHLXhwf/bE8FXJTQZmKN8ITMJVdqQ==';

CryptoJS.algo.EvpKDF.cfg.hasher = CryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create(); // default: MD5        
const decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(saltCiphertextB64, password);
console.log(decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the digest in the code must be explicitly specified as SHA-256 since OpenSSL v1.1.1i was used for encryption.
If the encryption was done with an OpenSSL version that uses MD5, the digest in the code must be modified accordingly.

**Edit:** As noted in the comment, the crypto functions [`createCipher()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatecipheralgorithm-password-options)/[`createDecipher()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatedecipheralgorithm-password-options) also use `EVP_BytesToKey()` as key derivation.
However, the following should be noted:

- Unlike CryptoJS, it is not possible to specify the digest, i.e. MD5 is used unchangeably. Thus, encryptions that applied SHA-256 for key derivation cannot be decrypted (what applies to the encryptions here).
- In contrast to CryptoJS, no salt is used by default. Therefore, salt creation and concatenation (`Salted__|<salt>|<cipherext>`) during encryption and separation during decryption would have to be implemented additionally. `createCipher()`/`createDecipher()` then has to be passed the concatenation of passphrase and salt.
- Both functions are deprecated since version 10.0.0 and should actually not be used.

A more robust approach to decrypt encryptions (with arbitrary digests in key derivation) using the crypto module is to apply [`createCipheriv()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatecipherivalgorithm-key-iv-options)/[`createDecipheriv()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatedecipherivalgorithm-key-iv-options) and a port of the required functionality of `EVP_BytesToKey()` to derive key and IV (various implementations can be found on the net).

**Security:** `EVP_BytesToKey()` is deemed to be a vulnerability these days. This is worsened by a low iteration count (like 1, which is used by OpenSSL), a broken digest (like MD5) or a missing salt (as is the default for crypto). Ultimately, this is why `createCipher()`/`createDecipher()` are deprecated. Instead of `EVP_BytesToKey()`, a more reliable key derivation function such as PBKDF2 or the more modern scrypt or Argon2 should be used.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly.  Unfortunately the system is not letting me upvote this because of too low of a reputation but it did let me accept this answer.

Comment: nodejs builtin 'crypto' _is_ OpenSSL and the now-deprecated `createCipher` and `createDecipher` methods (vs now-preferred `create{Cipher,Decipher}iv`) do EVP_BytesToKey -- with MD5 unchangeably, thus default-compatible only with <1.1.0, which are now endangered if not extinct.